# Calculate shipping costs on the basis of product weight

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

my math is not so good, but can you guys help me with this

**problem statement**
Suppose I have 4 books with weights and prices.

1. Book1, 0.5KG
2. Book2, 0.8KG
3. Book3, 1KG
4. Book4,  0.3KG

I have a base price (shipping cost) based on weight, which is **30 Rs Per 0.5KG**.
Now when I select "book 1", the shipping cost will be 30 Rs, but how can I get the shipping cost for book 2,book 3 and book 4?

Answer (score 1):

it's not related to any programming or algorithm , anyways
if

```
30Rs -> 0.5KG
x    -> 0.8Kg
```

then simply for Book2

```
x =  (30Rs*0.8KG)/0.5KG =  48Rs
```

similarly for book3 and book4:

```
book3 =  (30Rs*1KG)/0.5KG =  60Rs
book4 =  (30Rs*0.3KG)/0.5KG =  18Rs
```

another way to solve it is if every **30RS corresponds to 0.5KG** then by dividing each side by 5 then **6RS corresponds to 0.1KG**.

Book2 is **0.8KG** which is 8 times the value **0.1KG** then it must cost 8 times the value **6RS** so `8 * 6 = 48RS` similarly for **Book3 and *Book4* where

```
Book3 = 10 * 6 = 60RS
Book4 = 3 * 6 = 18RS
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pricing is in brackets, that is the cost for 0 - 0.5kg is 30RS, and 0.5 - 1kg is 60RS, then you have to do as follows:

First find how many brackets you have:

```
weight / bracketSize
```

For your books, this will be:

```
Book1: 0.5/0.5  // 1
Book2: 0.8/0.5  // 1.6
Book3: 1/0.5    // 2
Book4, 0.3/0.5  // 0.6
```

Then, you need to round that value *up* to the nearest whole number. How you do this will depend on what language you're using, but it's often called `Ceiling` or `ceil`:

```
Book1: Ceiling(1)    // 1
Book2: Ceiling(1.6)  // 2
Book3: Ceiling(2)    // 2
Book4, Ceiling(0.6)  // 1
```

Then multiply by price to get your answer.

```
Book1: 1 * 30    // 30
Book2: 2 * 30    // 60
Book3: 2 * 30    // 60
Book4, 1 * 30    // 30
```

In one line:

```
result = Ceiling(weight / bracketSize) * pricePerBracket
```